# Does composer update remove extra files from extension folder?

Tags: magento2, extensions, composer

I have installed an extension with composer and we have added custom translation files to the extension folder. If I update the extension with composer, do those extra files get wiped away or do they stay in place?

Another solution would of course be to put those files into our custom theme's folder, but my question still stands.

Comment: If overwriting with files of same name composer will throw an error basically asking what you want to do and behavior will differ depending in your chosen option. If filename are not the same or do not exist in composer source repo they should remain.

Comment: @DominicXigen Thank you for answering.